# Check Point URL filtering categories

Tags: checkpoint

What are the predefined categories in Check Point for URL filtering (e.g. Social Network, Media Stream, Pornography). Went through the documentation [Application Control and URL Filtering](http://dl3.checkpoint.com/paid/cf/CP_R75.40VS_ApplicationControlURLFiltering_AdminGuide.pdf?HashKey=1475857847_1cafc4c49c86de64346f6008d178dfa1&xtn=.pdf) but could not find the complete list of categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete list was found in [Checkpoint AppWiki](http://appwiki.checkpoint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The Application Control and URL Filtering Policy determines who can access which applications and sites from an organisation. The primary component of the Policy is the Rule Base.

Based on the Gaia's version, number of categories can change.

For Gaia version R75.20 and above, there are 60+ categories while versions prior to this have 40 categories. For more info, check this [link](https://forums.checkpoint.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=14139).

Full list of categories are available [here.](https://www.checkpoint.com/urlcat/categories.htm)

Hope it helps !!!